# Positioning in mPDF

Tags: php, html, position, absolute, mpdf

I am working on a business card application, where at the final stage you can generate a PDF file from HTML and CSS. What I am trying to achieve is to absolute position the elements on the image within a *div*, which has relative positioning. All of my elements are draggable on the card.

Here is my PHP file: (note: I shortened the file to be understandable)

```
<?php

$html = '<div class="card">
        <span id="company_card" class="draggable_data">BMW</span>
        <img class="bck_icon" src="redtop.jpg" alt="red">
        </div>';

include('mpdf/mpdf.php');

$mpdf = new mPDF();

$stylesheet = file_get_contents('test.css'); // external css
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
$mpdf->Output();
```

The CSS file is the following:

```
.bck_icon {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.card {
    margin: auto;
    width: 460px;
    height: 260px;
    position:relative;
}

#name_card {
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left:80px;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I know there are positioning issues in mPDF, but when I do not use the **div** element, then the elements inside the div will not fit the outside relative element.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The only consistent workaround for mPDFs positioning limitations, I have found, is to stick everything in a table.

Answer (score 4):

I encounter similar positioning problems with mPDF.  Some of them I solved by using negative margins.

For example, instead of attempting to use `position:absolute;` you could try to position the name on the card like this:

```
#name_card {
    margin-top: -70px;  // more or less
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

Another option to consider is using background-images: `background-image;` and `background-position`' CSS also works in mPDF.

Comment: an alternative is to use dompdf instead of mpdf, as it supports absolute positioning